# Different answers on function call at different positions

Tags: c, arrays

I have this code:

```
//function to delete the occurence of c in s
void squeeze(char s[], int  c) {
  int i,j;
  for(i=j=0;s[i]!='\0';i++)
    if(s[i]!=c)
       s[j++]=s[i];
  s[j]='\0';
}

//function to concatenate string 
void strca(char c[],char b[]){
  int i,j;
  i=j=0;
  while(c[i]!='\0')
    i++;
  c[i++]=' ';
  while((c[i++]=b[j++])!='\0')
    ;
}
```

Now when I call the functions in the main()

```
int main(void){
 1 char test[]="carmakarchile";
 2  //squeeze(test,'a');
 3 //printf("%s\n",test);
 4 char f[]="Magnificent";
 5 char n[]="King Rex";
 6 strca(f,n);
 7 squeeze(test,'a');
 8 printf("%s\n",test);
 9 printf("%s",f);
  }
```

gives the op:

> ```
>    King Rex
>    Magnificent King Rex
> ```

while removing the comment lines in 2 and 3 line and putting comment on 7 and 8 gives me:

> ```
>       crmkrchile
>       Magnificent King Rex
> ```

I just want to know why and how does the difference arise? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char f[]="Magnificent";
```

makes the array `f` just large enough to hold the string `"Magnificent"`, including the 0-terminator.

```
char n[]="King Rex";
strca(f,n);
```

happily writes outside the array bounds, invoking undefined behaviour, and apparently in this case overwriting your other array `test`.

If you declare the array large enough to hold the result of the concatenation,

```
char f[32] = "Magnificent";
```

for example, all will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your concatenate function writes past the c[] array. If you want to concatenate strings, you need to make sure to allocate enough memory for both strings to fit (including terminating `\0`).

Now in your example, you're just "lucky" that both f[] and n[] just happen to be next to each other in memory, so when you replace terminating null with a white space, it appears to be a concatenated string.